# Работа с GitHub

Tags: visual-studio, github, репозиторий

Решил начать пользоваться `GitHub`. Сделал репозиторий, залил (не помню как в этом и проблема). И скачал `GitHub Desktop` и при изменении файла в `Visual Studio` в GitHub desktop были видны изменения. Начал делать новый проект, и не могу теперь сделать подобное с другим проектом. Можете дать подробные инструкции?

Хотел бы добиться,
что бы было видно в приложении изменения в файле с другим проектом.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Спустя двое суток нашёл ответ на просторах англоязычного интернета. Даю ответ, вдруг кому-то понадобиться(Ответ для тех кто уже зарегистрирован, у кого есть репозиторий на **GitHub** и скачан **GitHub Desktop**

1. Так как у нас создан репозиторий, мы заходим в **GitHub Desktop** и
   там в меню File выбираем Clone Repository или *hot_key* - 
   Ctrl+Shift+O.
2. Заходим в вкладку GitHub.com и там выбираем внимание,уже созданный репозиторий на GitHub. И ниже вводим путь к папке в которой будем работать с проектом

*(для тех кто работает с Visual Studio и планирует заливать ВСЕ свои
    проекты на GitHub советую создать новую папку где будут создаваться
    все проекты VS)*

3. Нажимаем на кнопку `Clone` и ждем загрузку.
4. Теперь проверяем путь который мы вводили для репозитория. Там появилась папка с названием этого репозитория. Теперь все изменения которые мы будем вносить в этой папке будут видны в GitHub Desktop как на скриншоте из вопроса.

Comment: А чем Вам не подошло GitHub-расширение для визуалки? Просто интересуюсь, ибо, как по мне, все очень удобно организовано)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov а это вы о VSTS?

Comment: Собственно, да. Оно интегрировано в `Team Explorer`